# passing parenthesis in Preg_match() - php

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm not able to match parenthesis for below code rest of the conditions are working fine.

```
if (!preg_match(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 -,._\/\))]{10,50}$/",$phone))) 
                {
                $_SESSION['nameErr'] .= "<li>Phone should contain only letters, Numbers and special Characters(Collan(:), Hyphen(-), Comma(,), Underscore(_), Slash(/),Parenthesis()  are allowed) and Min limit 10 Characters  Max limit is 50 Characters.</li>"; 
                $errors = 1;
                }
```

Example :

011-45538691/92/93 (From 7:30 a.m. to 2:00 p.m.)

Comment: Is `!preg_match(!preg_match(` a typo? Please edit your question and add some test cases. What's the content of `$phone`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
if (!preg_match('%^[\w:,/()-]{10,50}$%', $phone)) {
     $_SESSION['nameErr'] .= "<li>Phone should contain only letters, Numbers and special Characters(Collan(:), Hyphen(-), Comma(,), Underscore(_), Slash(/),Parenthesis()  are allowed) and Min limit 10 Characters  Max limit is 50 Characters.</li>"; 
     $errors = 1;
}
```

---

### [image]

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UE6Nw6/3)

Comment: its not matching for this => 011-45538691/92/93 (From 7:30 a.m. to 2:00 p.m.)

Comment: it matches, check the regex demo updated with the above example.

Comment: I don't know which regex you're talking about but  https://regex101.com/r/UE6Nw6/3 , which is the same regex of my answer, is working: https://screenpresso.com/=WkwOf

Comment: `011-45538691/92/93 (From 7:30 a.m. to 2:00 p.m.)` doesn't match your question's parameters, you may want to update your question with some examples you need to match.

Comment: I did mention in the comments. but still, i will update my question.